# Book about a Psi/empath police detective false coded body

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about an organ robbed body that has false genetic ID because the dead person is hiding from a crime lord after running off with the boss wife.

Comment: This is very terse at the moment so could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?